# Theme Modified By Updates

Tags: themes

Good day all,

Congratulation for the informative site. I have downloaded a free WP theme and modified to my needs successfully.

I have then found out that changes in the original them will affect the modified them. Yesterday, the original theme had updates, which I did not manually allowed. However, this morning my theme has been changed. Colors and fonts are back to original. Everything else stayed the way I have created it (pics, logo, layout, script). I kindly have a few questions:

-Are those the only changes (color, fonts) or I should expect others?
-Will my logo, my pictures, my layout ever be effected by the theme updates?
-With those changes already in place, can I now create a child theme?

Thank you.
Best regards.
Air

Answer (score 1):

Based on your text, I'm assuming you changed the logo, pictures, layout, etc. through a "theme options" section in the WP Admin, instead of editing css/js/php files directly?

Whenever a theme is updated, typically (though this depends on theme) only the files are changed/overwritten. The types of changes you made are stored in the database and therefore shouldn't be overwritten by a theme update.

I suggest making a child theme now and using child themes for every site you build going forward. Just an FYI though, when you create a child theme, you'll have to set up the logo, colors, menus, etc. all over again if you set them up using theme options in the WP admin. At least this time though when you make any file-based changes they won't be overwritten.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I used WP admin for those changes. 
There is plenty of info (on this website as well) how to proceed with child themes. 
What is not really clear to me is how I create a child theme with the existing modified theme (called Keinzen).  Do I have to ignore it and start from scratch the first child theme (uploading pics, uploading logo, adding pages…….)? Or I can use Keinzen and modify files (colors, fonts) up it?
Thank you again.
Air

Comment: What I'd do is keep what you have right now, and create a child theme on top of it. Basically, follow this document: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes --- your pages and pictures will still be there, but you'll probably have to make the color adjustments again, set up the menus, and select the logo. If you edited any of the Keinzen JS/PHP files, I suggest downloading those from the Keinzen folder and uploading them into the child theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify *where* did you download theme from. I don't quite follow if you performed the update in the end or not.

Assuming you meant official WP theme repository then mechanics of update are essentially removing the whole folder and placing a fresh copy in its place. This shouldn't have had any *partial* effect on file-based changes.

Typical and reliable practice is for all file changes or additions to be contained in child theme, in case parent theme is ever expected to update.